# how to import 'twilio' package in a python jupyter notebook?

Tags: twilio

I tried to import 'twilio' package in my python jupyter notebook by the commands:

import twilio

print(twilio.**version**)

Error message appeared: ImportError: No module named twilio

I already installed twilio using a terminal as following:

sudo pip install twilio

When I used Spyder by typing 'Spyder' on a terminal, I sucessfully ran the import twilio and print(twilio.**version**) commands. Now how to I import twilio in the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a different installation of Python.

From Jupyter run:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

Then run Python from your command line (or however else you use it) and note the version.

The second way to check would be
    import os
    try:
        user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
    except KeyError:
        user_paths = []

Then from your OSX/Linux command line type:
    which python

If either of those two tests differ, then you're referencing a different version of Python.